# When exactly are "preloaded fonts" loaded on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, material-design, android-fonts

When I use the [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#java) feature on Android, I can add a preloading strategy by adding this code to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="preloaded_fonts" 
           android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
```

When exactly is this loaded? On app startup? On installation? If it's on app startup, and I am using the font on the **very first screen**, is there any performance difference at all?

Comment: I have exactly this issue now. The downloadable font on the first screen takes a split second too long. It show roboto font and half a second later it swaps to the specified font. Even **WITH** the preloading strategy.. Any ideas on that?

Comment: As far as I remember I couldn't see any effect at all from "preloading" fonts

Comment: So any suggestions how to handle this properly?

Comment: @Tobi You can use XML fonts, they're bundled with the APK and won't cause a delay (but a larger APK size)

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts#predeclaring-fonts

> Layout inflation and resource retrieval are synchronous tasks. By
> default, the first attempt to retrieve fonts triggers a request to the
> font provider, and therefore increases the first layout time. To avoid
> the delay, you can pre-declare fonts that need retrieving in your
> manifest. After the system retrieves the font from the provider, it is
> available immediately. If the font retrieval takes longer than
> expected, the system aborts the fetching process and uses the default
> font.

Comment: That doesn't say when the loading happens

Comment: From the top diagram of the site I think the font downloaded async when you download the app. Then the font cached. If another app uses the same font the app uses it from the cache. If the app small enough and starts before the font download finished then the default font will be used, and the next app start the custom font will be.